# How to play, record and edit the audio in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

Here I need to develop an IOS app consists of record,play and edit the audio.I done the Audio Recording and Playing by using the AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer.

But I want how to edit the audio,and save it. Is there any way to do.kindly help me

Recording:

```
AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                      initWithURL:audioFileURL
                      settings:audioSettings
                      error:nil];
[audioRecorder record];
```

Playing:

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];
[audioPlayer play
```

Here I have included the sample code for recording and palying the audio, but how can i edit the audio linke in this Yotube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWz2x9dXpsM

Comment: you may need to define what you mean by "edit audio"

Comment: I think you mean trimming of audio file.

Comment: @bennythemink "edit audio" means see this youtube link like this we need to edit the audio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWz2x9dXpsM

Comment: @dineshprasanna simply posting a link to a Youtube video and expecting people to view that to figure out what problem you wish resolving is, is not very polite. You should at least describe your problem in the question and explain what you have already attempted to solve the issue. I respectively suggest you edit your question to reflect the above.

Comment: @Dineshprasanna Did you get the solution to edit the audio file?

Comment: @Anurag Sharma No, I didn't get any solution to edit the audio file. Instead Just cut the audio file which will be the required portions and finally merge those into a single

I am sure, its not a good approach for large size audio or not. Since based on my requirement audio size is too small

Answer (score 2):

Audio recording can be done using AVFoundation framework of apple but editing of audio is kinda difficult process. So I suggest you to do it using open source library projects in iOS.

You can use [The Amazing Audio Engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/) which provides great quality of audio recording, Audio Filtering and Audio Mixing. The Amazing Audio is build in Non-ARC and is very light, thread safe.

You can also download the sample of Amazing Audio Engine from [Github](https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'm using The Amazing Audio Engine. But i cant write an filter audio into my document director.. can u plz share any samples

Answer (score 0):

Check this link once.In this example how to play audio and how to record the audio using AVAudioplayer Framework.
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/

Comment: I Used this is the reference code for developing the record and play,but i dont know how to edit the audio

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extended Audio File Services. have a look at the reference for ExtAudioFileRead & ExtAudioFileWrite (they have sample code) then you can open one audio file read it, trim it and then write the new one.Go here

[Extended Audio File Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)